# Visual Studio OpenAPI project needs to be restored Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, blazor, openapi

I am using Blazor WebAssembly ASP.NET Core hosted and wanna add a **SwaggerAPI** as **OpenAPI** service to my Blazor.Shared .Net standard 2.1 library but it always throws an error. When I choose what  `swagger.JSON` file to upload it tells me in a dialog:
**"The project must be restored for the service reference to be added"** (*translated*)

I did run `dotnet restore` from the terminal in the project path but it did not fix it.

Does anyone have any solutions to this problem? I saw someone earlier doing the same thing onto the same library from Blazor WebAssembly and it worked for him.

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

The problem was **.Net-Standard** versioning. Downgrading to **.Net-Standard** 2.0 solved it.